# CoreBluetooth: How to figure out if the not-connected BLE device is in the range on the background mode? (Xcode 12.5, Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

CoreBluetooth: How to figure out if the not-connected BLE device is in the range on the background mode? (Xcode 12.5, Swift 5)

1. I have an `identifier` of the BLE device
2. I'm able to retrieve the BLE device on the background via `centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [identifier])`
3. The peripheral itself does not support connection, so I CAN'T DO: `centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)` and call`peripheral.readRSSI()` on it . I tested and I can connect and read RSSI on another device without any problem.

---

So my question is how to read `RSSI` on not connected device? Or maybe there is another smart way to figure it out if the device is not in range on the background mode?

Comment: If you can't connect to the peripheral then there isn't anything else you can do.

Comment: What’s the point of this peripheral if it does not support being connect to?

Comment: yes, @cora you are right there is no point :/